# Heronian isosceles triangles

Tags: diophantine-equations, triangles, project-euler

This is a problem from Project Euler, problem 94.

The problem asks about isosceles triangles with integer sides (differing by 1 unit, e.g, 5-5-6) and integer area, which are known to be Heronian Triangles.

Now as per the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle#Isosceles_Heronian_triangles), all heronian isosceles triangles have sides of the form:

$$
a = u^{2} + v^{2} \\
b = 2(u^2 - v^2)
$$

for coprime integers `u` and `v` with `u>v`.

As per the question, the difference between a and b is 1, which reduces the equations to

$$
u^2 - 3v^2 = 1 \space for \space b > a \\
3v^2 - u^2 = 1 \space for \space a > b
$$

Clearly both are of the form of Pell's equation. And the second being a `negative Pell equation` with `D = 3`, **[it is not solvable](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/hardy_williams.html)** effectively removing any possibility of triangles with `a > b`.

As I solved for the 1st equation, I did not get all the possible Heronian isosceles triangles. However, on the web I can find solutions considering the case of `a > b` as well.

Where am I doing wrong ? Isn't the question asking about Heronian isosceles triangles ?
And, if the wiki is right, how can we have triangles with `a > b` when the corresponding Pell's equation is not solvable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you wrote down for generating the Heronian triangles is not quite correct. For example, we can take $u$ and $v$ odd, $a=\frac{1}{2}(u^2+v^2)$, $b=u^2-v^2$, with $u\gt v$.

That will give you the Pellian $3v^2-u^2=2$, which does have solutions.

Comment: I see. Looks like I didn't notice the part where they say "All isosceles Heronian triangles are given by **rational multiples** of".

Comment: I just checked, they kind of get it right, though they should have given an iff condition, since not all rational multiples work.